# How to create ffmpeg mosaic with empty cells?

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to create video mosaic with ffmpeg.

Two videos with horizontal stack:

`ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:1080[v0];[1]scale=-1:1080[v1];[v0][v1]hstack=inputs=2[vmap]" -map "[vmap]" output.mp4`

How can I replace vid1.mp4 with black background and save the stack with 2 elements?
I can add blackvideo.mp4, but it should be easier, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the empty cell has to be the same size and duration as vid1, then it's best to just paint the canvas of vid1 black.

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]drawbox=t=fill:c=black,scale=-1:1080[v0];[1]scale=-1:1080[v1];[v0][v1]hstack=inputs=2[vmap]" -map "[vmap]" output.mp4
```

If you just want black space to the left of vid2, pad vid2

```
ffmpeg -i vid2.mp4 -vf "scale=-1:1080,pad=w=300+iw:h=ih:x=300:y=0" output.mp4
```

This will add 300px of black to the left of vid2.